# How to change the app description

Tags: facebook-graph-api

After changing the app description in the app settings page (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/(ID)/summary), the graph API returns the new description  ([https://graph.facebook.com/162099160534480][1]), but the app profile page (http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=162099160534480&sk=info) still shows the old description. Even after a couple days the description on the app profile page is not updated.

Is there any other way to change the description or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it seems like Bug that APP description is not updating ..

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's a bug. It seems that Facebook made some changes but forgot to update some parts. See also http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=20055